# Twitter Ads Api - Objects ID System (numeral / string)

Tags: api, twitter

I'm using Twitter ads api (example request: [https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/{{account-id}}/campaigns](https://ads-api.twitter.com/8/accounts/%7B%7Baccount-id%7D%7D/campaigns)), and I'm having trouble understanding why I get various objects IDs (campaign ID, Item Line ID, Ad ID, etc) from the API as a short string, for example: "ahab1" or "cahy5", and in their management system in the website I can see those IDs as numbers, for example: 61066011.

It's really confusing.

Does anyone know why it is so?
It seems that the short strings I get from the api could probably not be globally unique, as they seem too short. And besides, it's hard to know if I'm fetching the right information this way. I thought maybe they are encoded, but I don't think it's base64 encoded. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Ads API all IDs (except for `user_id` and `tweet_id`) are base-36 encoded. On the Ads UI however these entities are represented in base-10. More details can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-ads-api/campaign-management/overview#campaigns-and-ad-groups)